# place a footer element to the bottom of a div without using margin - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place footer to the bottom of a div using bootstrap without applying margin to the div I want to push to the bottom of the div as footer. This is my attempt but the footer aligns to the top

```
<div style="background-color:#191919;" class="container">
    <h3 style="color: #32CD32; font-family: Copperplate; align:left;">
    HEADER TEXT
    </h3>
    <h5>... reaching out</h5>
    <hr style="width:101.6%;">


    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <nav id="main_menu">
            <div align="center" class="menu_wrap">

            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="contents">
                The contents in each page
            </div>
        </div>


        <footer style="color:#fff; text-align:center;"> &copy 2016 All rights reserved
            <br> For more information visit our website
        </footer>
    </div>

</div>
```

Please how can I place the footer to the bottom of .

Comment: Can you please add a code example? codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Here is a plunk I have made>>>>>>> http://plnkr.co/edit/Zwd5DYo2VcZY7DCNQCTg?p=preview

Comment: your code is practically right . But you did not closed some div. , you won't be needing css is if you are using footer . close your divs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that, i think the faster way for you is this case is using `position: absolute` on the footer;

First move out you footer from `.col-lg-12` to be a directly children of `.container`. I also added a class `.myFooter`

```
<footer class="myFooter">
      copy 2016 All rights reserved
      <p>You can visit our website for more info</p>
</footer>
```

And then the css. Don't use css inline on the markup. I moved the color and text-align to the class.

```
.myFooter {
      color:#fff;
      text-align:center;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
}
```

The last step is to add `position:relative` to the `.container`. That way the `position:absolute` on `.myFooter` works properly.

```
.container {
      position: relative;
}
```

Here is a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ypl82cdqxuHFIjAcpRo8?p=preview

Comment: is this bootrap approach

Comment: What do you mean bootstrap approach? Bootstrap is only a framework, how you use its code to accomplish your tasks is up to you...

Comment: The text is floated to the left

Comment: How can I float it to the center using text-align:center

Comment: what do you want to float to the center? to align to the center use `text-align: center;` or `margin: auto` on the element you want to align. You don't use float on this case

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<title>
Lugah Salisu Foundation
</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

@media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
    body{font-size: 10px;}
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
    body{font-size: 14px;}
}


h3{
     font-size: 300%; 
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     clear: both;
     margin-left: 7px;
}
h5{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    clear: both;
}
hr{
    margin: 0px;
}

.container {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    height:500px;
    max-height:500px !important;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

 .nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block!important;
 }
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:transparent!important;
    color:#d3d3d3;
}
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 10px 4px!important;
    color:#fff;

}

.golden-base {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight:bold;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0.3em; 
  -webkit-margin-after: 0.2em;
}
.golden1 {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF65C, #3A2C00);
  text-shadow: -0.02em -0.03em 0.005em rgba(255, 223, 0, 0.60);
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


</style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:#1f5060;">

<div style="background-color:#191919;" class="container">
<h3 style="color: #32CD32; font-family: Copperplate; align:left;">
HEADER TEXT
</h3>
 <h5>... reaching out</h5> <hr style="width:101.6%;">


 <div class="col-lg-12">
              <nav id="main_menu">
                                <div align="center" class="menu_wrap"></div>
                                   <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                                     <li class="sub-menu"><a href="home.html"><small>Home</small></a></li> |                    
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
</div>
 </nav> 
  <footer style="color:#fff; text-align:center;">  &copy 2016 All rights reserved 

<div class="row">
<div class="contents">
The contents in each page
</div>
</div>                           





</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```